# why my styles from .module.scss dosen't work

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, vite

this is my Sublayout.module.scss file that im using

```
.pl-6 {
    padding-left: 6rem !important;
}
.pr-6 {
    padding-right: 6rem !important;
}
.pl-12 {
    padding-left: 12rem !important;
}
.pr-12 {
    padding-right: 12rem !important;
}
```

then i imported my styles from Sublayout.module.css file and started using that in my classNames but it doesnt apply and just get the undefined on my classNames instead ...

```
import { FC, ReactNode } from "react";
import { Grid } from "@payping/web-components";
import styles from "./Sublayout.module.scss";

interface Props {
  children?: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
}

export const SubLayout: FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const { children, className } = props;
  const sizes = Grid.useBreakpoint();

  // TODO not sure about top and bottom padding
  if (sizes.xxl) {
    console.log("xxl screen");
    return <div className={`${styles.pr12} ${styles.pl12} w-100 ${className}`}>{children}</div>;
  }
  if (sizes.xl) {
    console.log("xl screen");
    return <div className={`${styles.pr6} ${styles.pl6}  ${className}`}>{children}</div>;
  }
  if (sizes.lg) {
    console.log("lg screen");
    return <div className={`pr-3 pl-3 w-100 ${className}`}>{children}</div>;
  }
  if (sizes.md) {
    console.log("md screen");
    return <div className={`pr-2 pl-2 w-100 ${className}`}>{children}</div>;
  }
  if (sizes.sm) {
    console.log("sm screen");
    return <div className={`pr-1 pl-1 pe-10 ps-10 w-100 ${className}`}>{children}</div>;
  }
  if (sizes.xs) {
    console.log("xs screen");
    return <div className={`pr-1 pl-1 w-100 ${className}`}>{children}</div>;
  }

  return <div className={`ps-6 pe-6 w-100 ${className}`}>{children}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the naming of classNames in my Sublayout.module.scss :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ailFY.png)

then i edited my classNames on Sublayout.module.scss :

```
.pl6 {
    padding-left: 6rem !important;
}
.pr6 {
    padding-right: 6rem !important;
}
.pl12 {
    padding-left: 12rem !important;
}
.pr12 {
    padding-right: 12rem !important;
}
```

then every thing went ok and im happy again :)